# Are Twitter's ID time ordered?

Tags: twitter

My question is whether Twitter's id associated to each tweet is time ordered, i.e. ids of more recent tweets are bigger numbers.

For instance: [this tweet](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/623261510727561216)
has an id of `623261510727561216`, and was published at 12:41 AM - 21 Jul 2015

[This other tweet](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/623260219477524481) 
has an id of `623260219477524481`, and was published at 12:36 AM - 21 Jul 2015. IDs difference `623261510727561216−623260219477524481 = 1291250036735`, a positive difference for a positive time difference.

The only thing I want to ascertain from this is just an order, which tweet was published first.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Twitter ids are time ordered. According to twitter [doc](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/twitter-ids-json-and-snowflake), the full ID is composed of a timestamp, a worker number, and a sequence number. So basically the first part of the id is the timestamp, so it can be sorted by time. ( But I am not sure how many bits are used for timestamp for twitter ).

Answer (score 0):

## Extracting timestamp from a tweet ID

[Tweet IDs are k-sorted within a second bound](https://blog.twitter.com/engineering/en_us/a/2010/announcing-snowflake). We can extract the timestamp for a tweet ID by right shifting the tweet ID by 22 bits and adding the Twitter epoch time of 1288834974657.

**Python code to get UTC timestamp of a tweet ID**

```
def get_tweet_timestamp(tid):
    offset = 1288834974657
    tstamp = (tid >> 22) + offset
    utcdttime = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(tstamp/1000)
    print(str(tid) + " : " + str(tstamp) + " => " + str(utcdttime))
```

[Source](https://github.com/oduwsdl/tweetedat)